# Deciding when certain elements of $L[[x]]$, coming from recursions, are algebraic over $L(x)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory, power-series, recurrences

Let $L$ be a finite field of characteristic $2$. Suppose that for some $k > 0$ we are given elements $A(0),\, A(1), \dots, \, A(k-1)$ and $c(0),\, c(1), \dots,\, c(k-1)$ of $L[t]$. Define $A(n)$ inductively by $A(n+k) = \sum c(j)A(n+j)$. I'll say that $n$ is a "jump number" if $A(n)$ is an $L$-linear combination of $A(r)$ with $r < n$. Let $J$ in $L[[x]]$ be $\sum x^n$, where the exponents are the jump numbers.

**Questions**:  Is there a decision procedure for determining from the initial data above whether $J$ is algebraic over the field $L(x)$? And when it is, for determining an equation that it satisfies over $L(x)$?

**Example**: Suppose that $A(0)=A(1)=A(2)=0$, that $A(3)=t$, and that $A(n+4)=t^4A(n)+tA(n+1)$. The first few odd jump numbers are $1,5,17,21,65,69,81,85$. A corollary of the (technically difficult but elementary) study, by Nicolas and Serre, of the action of the Hecke operator T3 on mod $2$ modular forms of level $1$ is that the set of jump numbers consists of $0$ together with the $2^a(1+4b)$ where $b$ runs over the sums of distinct powers of $4$. It follows from this that the cube of $J+J^2$ is $x^3/(1+x^4)$. So algebraicity holds in this case.

**Remark**: It seems implausible that $J$ is always algebraic over $L(x)$. But in a number of examples that I've looked at, particularly those where the recursions come from the action of Hecke operators, as in the example, there is computer evidence for $J$ being algebraic. One may also replace $L$ by a finite field of odd 
characteristic, and ask the same questions.

Comment: To prove that a power series is not algebraic it is often useful to use Christol's theorem: If $L$ is a finite field, then $\sum a_i x^i$ is algebraic if and only if the sequence $(a_i)$ is automatic. To show that a sequence is not automatic, it often suffices to look at local patterns. For example, if for every $k$ there exists some $i$, such that $a_i=a_{i+1}=\dots=a_{i+k}=a$, then there exists some $\delta>0$ and infinitely many $x$, such that $a_i=a$ for all $i\in[x, (1+\delta)x$.